Nothing Displaying on my LCD screen: Nucleo F401RE
Coding in arm keil studio, my code is correct because it is built. But nothing is displaying to my LCD screen and I'm trying to figure out my problem. The only thing the LCD is doing is lighting up and not displaying the message I want it to print when I connect it to my nucleo board 5V.
#include "mbed.h"
#include "TextLCD.h"
#include <string>

//TextLCD lcd(RS, E, D4, D5, D6, D7);                         
TextLCD lcd(PA_0, PA_1, PA_4, PB_0, PC_1, PC_0);

int main(){
   string ampm = "AM";
   int temp = 97;
   while(true){
       lcd.cls();
       lcd.printf("12:09 %s %iF\n", ampm, temp);
       wait(1.0);
   }
   
}


wiring to my nucleo board
my soldering
I've tried everything, messing with code, getting another board and soldering that one too, nothing is displaying. The only thing my LCD screen does, is light up.

Are you sure it's not displaying the message? What's the unit of time used in the wait() call? Try it without the call to wait() or without looping.

Also, check Rod Coleman's comment here: https://os.mbed.com/forum/helloworld/topic/2631/?page=1#comment-13919
